# Sort an array based on two other arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-multisort

I have a total of three arrays

**Array 1**

```
array1 = Array( 
    [0] => Array(
        [name] => John 
        [city] => San Francisco 
        [state] => CA 
    ) 
    [1] => Array(
        [name] => Smith 
        [city] => Atlanta 
        [state] => GA 
    ) 
    [2] => Array(
        [name] => Peter 
        [city] => New York 
        [state] => NY 
    ) 
    [3] => Array(
        [name] => Mary 
        [city] => San Jose 
        [state] => CA 
    ) 
)
```

**Array 2 (sorted on average age)**

```
array2 = Array(
    [0] => CA 
    [1] => NY 
    [2] => GA
)
```

**Array 3 (sorted based on population)**

```
array3 = Array(
    [0] => New York 
    [1] => San Francisco 
    [2] => Atlanta 
    [3] => San Jose
)
```

How do I sort array 1 based on array 2 first and then by array 3. I want the following output:

**Sorted Array 1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [city] => San Francisco
            [state] => CA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mary
            [city] => San Jose
            [state] => CA
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Peter
            [city] => New York
            [state] => NY
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Smith
            [city] => Atlanta
            [state] => GA
        )

)
```

I tried using `array_multisort` for achieving this, but it's not working, e.g.

```
array_multisort($array2,$array3,$array1)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please confirm your intent. You wish to order by state age and then by state population? What problem are you attempting to solve.

Comment: Post the code of your 3 arrays. Is array 1 an array of arrays or an array of strings?

Comment: array 2 and 3 is are just array of strings while array 1 is a multidimensional array

Comment: Yes, I am trying to order array 1 first by state age and then by city population.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to sort `$array1` by `$array2` and `$array3` to produce the results you want:

```php
<?php

$array1 = array(
    array('name' => 'John',  'city' => 'San Francisco', 'state' => 'CA'),
    array('name' => 'Smith', 'city' => 'Atlanta',       'state' => 'GA'),
    array('name' => 'Peter', 'city' => 'New York',      'state' => 'NY'),
    array('name' => 'Mary',  'city' => 'San Jose',      'state' => 'CA'),
);

$array2 = array(
    'CA',
    'NY',
    'GA'
);

$array3 = array(
    'New York',
    'San Francisco',
    'Atlanta',
    'San Jose'
);

usort(
    $array1,
    function ($element1, $element2) use ($array2, $array3) {
        $state_sort_order = array_flip($array2);

        $element1_state_sort_order = $state_sort_order[$element1['state']];
        $element2_state_sort_order = $state_sort_order[$element2['state']];

        $state_sort_result = $element1_state_sort_order - $element2_state_sort_order;

        if ($state_sort_result === 0) {
            $city_sort_order = array_flip($array3);
            $element1_city_sort_order = $city_sort_order[$element1['city']];
            $element2_city_sort_order = $city_sort_order[$element2['city']];

            return $element1_city_sort_order - $element2_city_sort_order;
        } else {
            return $state_sort_result;
        }
    }
);

print_r($array1);
```

Again, [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) seemed to be the choice with the most flexibility. There might be a way to figure out how to use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), but I couldn't tell based on the data you've given.

I use a function closure, capturing `$array2` and `$array3` from the outer scope to do the sorting. It defines a comparison function for `usort` to apply to elements of `$array1` to determine sort order.  In this function, `$element1` and `$element2` each receive the value of elements from `$array1` to process for comparison, e.g `'Smith,Atlanta,GA'`, or `'Mary,San Jose,CA'`.

For each element, I extract the city and state portions of the elements. If you flip `$array2` and `$array3`, they become lookup tables for sort order when you index them by `$city` and `$state`, respectively.

The rest is just returning the difference between city sort orders if the state sort orders are equal, else just return the state sort orders.

Comment: This is great. Let me try this. I think I misquoted on my previous comment. It is not array of strings. The arrays are structured as follows: array 2= Array ( [0] => CA [1] => NY [2] => GA) and array 3 = Array ( [0] => New York [1] => San Francisco [2] => Atlanta [3] => San Jose ). The array 1 is structured in similar fashion. I am sure the usort function will be easier with this structure. I will try to change the usort function accorindingly.

Comment: I get an error at the line function ... use... I think php is throwing an error at use. Any idea why? I am using PHP 5.3

Comment: By the way, this is my php version info, where the code I posted runs just fine: PHP Version => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

System => Linux 3.2.0-33-generic-pae #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 18 16:39:21 UTC 2012 i686

Comment: Done. This works like a charm. I wanted to ask one last thing. What if I have another array with zipcodes (sorted by some criteria) and I want to use it to sort my original array1, how do I incorporate this into usort. I think I have an idea, but still thought it will be a good idea to ask you? :)

Comment: Simple enough. Just capture the zip codes array into the function as well, in the usort closure's use clause.  Incorporate whatever zip-code related comparison logic you need to perform into the rest of what the closure is doing.

Comment: Thanks @Danny. I have to use at least 4 more arrays to sort the original array1. I will use the same logic and see if I can work it out. You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).  You can define a user-defined function that compares the elements of array 1 with array 2 and 3 and use that callback in usort to perform the sort.

Comment: array_multisort takes the sort order of the first array and simply applies it to all of the others passed, if I'm reading this right.  So, arrays 3 and 1 get sorted based on the sorting of array 2.

Comment: I dont think usort will work, since usort is used to sort arrays based on one or more fields in the same array. I am trying to sort one array based on values in different arrays.

Comment: Abegosum, I think what you said makes sense. So I tried using just array_multisort($array2,$array1) to see if array 1 gets sorted at least by the values in array 2 and that isn't working either. So I am now confused what array_multisort is used for.

Comment: @Danny - I have always used usort with only one array. Can you provide an example of how can I used it to sort an array based on another array.

Comment: @amey1908, I've added an answer where I use usort to sort the array by the other two arrays.

Comment: @Danny - Array 1, 2, 3 are structured as follows: **array1** = Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => John [city] => San Francisco [state] => CA ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Smith [city] => Atlanta [state] => GA ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Peter [city] => New York [state] => NY ) [3] => Array ( [name] => Mary [city] => San Jose [state] => CA ) **array2** = Array ( [0] => CA [1] => NY [2] => GA) and **array3** = Array ( [0] => New York [1] => San Francisco [2] => Atlanta [3] => San Jose )